# how to implement push notification in flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

Hi I am trying to implement push notification in flutter how to display as notification can any one help,I am able to listen as I am getting notification but I am not able to see the msg and it is appearing as alert but I want as notification can any one help and in android or iOS we should right in manifest file and app delegate file what about this in flutter

and my code look like this

```
 class PushMessagingExample extends StatefulWidget {
 @override
 _PushMessagingExampleState createState() => new _PushMessagingExampleState();
 }

class _PushMessagingExampleState extends State<PushMessagingExample> {
String _homeScreenText = "Waiting for token...";
bool _topicButtonsDisabled = false;

final FirebaseMessaging _firebaseMessaging = new FirebaseMessaging();
final TextEditingController _topicController =
new TextEditingController(text: 'topic');

Future<Null> _showItemDialog(Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
final Item item = _itemForMessage(message);
showDialog<Null>(
    context: context,
    child: new AlertDialog(
      content: new Text("Item ${message} has been updated"),
      actions: <Widget>[
        new FlatButton(
            child: const Text('CLOSE'),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.pop(context, false);
            }),
        new FlatButton(
            child: const Text('SHOW'),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.pop(context, true);
            }),
      ],
    )).then((bool shouldNavigate) {
  if (shouldNavigate == true) {
    _navigateToItemDetail(message);
  }
});
}

 Future<Null> _navigateToItemDetail(Map<String, dynamic> message) async     {
final Item item = _itemForMessage(message);
// Clear away dialogs
Navigator.popUntil(context, (Route<dynamic> route) => route is PageRoute);
if (!item.route.isCurrent) {
  Navigator.push(context, item.route);
}
}

  @override
 void initState() {
  super.initState();
_firebaseMessaging.configure(
  onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) {
    print("onMessage: $message");
    print(message);
    _showItemDialog(message);
  },
  onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) {
    print("onLaunch: $message");
    print(message);
    _navigateToItemDetail(message);
  },
  onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) {
    print("onResume: $message");
    print(message);
    _navigateToItemDetail(message);
  },
);
_firebaseMessaging.requestNotificationPermissions(
    const IosNotificationSettings(sound: true, badge: true, alert: true));
_firebaseMessaging.onIosSettingsRegistered
    .listen((IosNotificationSettings settings) {
  print("Settings registered: $settings");
});
_firebaseMessaging.getToken().then((String token) {
  assert(token != null);
  setState(() {
    _homeScreenText = "Push Messaging token: $token";
  });
  print(_homeScreenText);
});
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return new Scaffold(


    body: new Material(
      child: new Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          new Center(
            child: new Text(_homeScreenText),
          ),

        ],
      ),
    ));
  }

  }
```

Comment: Able to recieve push notifications in android but in ios in onmessage and onresume not able to get that data.

Answer (score 16):

Push notifications in Flutter can be particularly difficult because you have to do twice the work to get them working with Android & iOS' particular implementations (both of which are, of course, quite different).

I've been building the OneSignal SDK for flutter. It will be ready within a few days. We work pretty hard to simplify push notifications as much as possible, and it's easy to use our SDK in a GDPR compliant way.

The repo is here (https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Flutter-SDK), it's open source and we welcome contributions from anyone. It acts as a wrapper on top of the native Android & iOS OneSignal SDK's.

Comment: How is it complicated? It seems straight forward to me. You just follow the instructions one by one and you're good to go.

Comment: Is there a recommended way to handle background notifications for OneSignal? I need to call a Flutter method when a background notifications is received.

Comment: It is not "particularly difficult". You say that because you are marketing your product.

Comment: What about Android 10? As mentioned in docs `Tested from Android 4.0.3 (API level 15) to Android 9.0 (28)`

Answer (score 7):

If you're trying to put messages on the lock screen, make sure you're sending a "notification" message type, rather than a "data" message that will be delivered to the running app. You can learn more about the [different types of Firebase messages](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages) in the Firebase developer guide.

Comment: I am getting notifications in lock screen but i am not getting when the screen is in active and when the other apps are opened the notifications of this app should be show

Comment: I am not getting on locked screen can you share ur experience? what should i added ? @sivakumar

Comment: @Aliy, did you find solution of locked screen notification?

Answer (score 3):

**1. Add Dependency**

For sending push notifications we use a plugin called firebase_messaging…

https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging

Open your pubspec.yaml file and add this dependency

*dependencies:
**firebase_messaging: ^6.0.9***

**2. Firebase Account**

Make sure you have a firebase account before proceeding.

In the next step, you should be able to download the **google-services.json** file.

After downloading the file, make sure to copy it inside the app/ folder of your Android project.

**3. Android Manifest**

**ADD**

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

*Add these lines to [project]/android/build.gradle*

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
}
```

*Add these lines to [project]/android/app/build.gradle*

```
 dependencies {
   implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
   implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
   implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
   implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.2.3'
   implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.4.4'

   // Add the SDK for Firebase Cloud Messaging
   testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
   androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
   androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

 }


 apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**DONE**

Comment: I did Android in an hour, but IOS I spent a week spent and nothing works, there is just a terrible instruction they always have everything more complicated than in Android.

Comment: Me too, now got stuck in Flutter IOS cant find ‘Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.debug.xcconfig’ error and could not find my way out, tried almost everything mentioned on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2):

Let me Give you the Most Prominent Solution for Pushing Notifications with Flutter, which i came Across Today, it is, `locally` it is a package by **samuelezedi.com** it Sends local Notifications. Schedule it, and Best part is it Doesn't need much setup like we always do with `flutter_local_notification` people are loosing their Strands  after using it, it is So complicated and not Begineer Friendly, So We found `locally` locally will help you.

### Sending Local Push Notifications

```
Locally locally = Locally(
      context: context,
      payload: 'test',
      pageRoute: null, //Link to which page you want to open
      appIcon: 'mipmap/ic_launcher', //Icon of your app, in android>app>src>main>res>drawable-v21 I put my png Icon..
  );

  locally.show(title: "Remaindero to use Toodolee", message: "Hey do this work");
```

See this is How easy it was to Send a push notification,

### Sending Local Scheduled Notifications

Just instead of `.show` use `.schedule` this will help you to schedule

```
 locally.schedule(title: "Toodolee Reminder, message: "Hey have a run, duration: Duration(seconds: 5));
```

Their Documentation is so Good and amazing and newbie like me could understand it so beautifullly, one thing i could not found here is the support of custom Sounds.

Here is the Link of the Documentation.
https://pub.dev/packages/locally

Thanks alot