# Flutter Push Notification to user

Tags: flutter, dart, push-notification, flutter-dependencies

I am working on a client application ordering products, I want to `push notification` for specific user when his order accepted and when delivery arrive to him, i am new in flutter and i don't know how start.

**What is the correct way to implement that and achieve good performance, I don’t know which way to start ?**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to implement push notification in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46578907/how-to-implement-push-notification-in-flutter)

Comment: @LOLWTFasdasd Unfortunately that not help me

Comment: Why does it not help you? You need to be more specific so that we can help you. Are you using firebase? Are you using your own push notification service?

Comment: I need help in that I have API return me true if Order Accepted then i Should Push notification to user to till him his order accepted. what is the correct way to implement that ? i didn't work in that before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try reading the documentation for this package, maybe this will help you.
[Local Push Notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications)
It stores the notification you want to send to user locally on their phone and send it on a timer or when you trigger some action. You must initialize the package in the main function of your `main.dart`. I've tried this package with an Alarm app, it works fine.

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me it push notification when action occurred, now i should listen API till get true how can i do that you have any information.

Comment: @Nehalosama Can you provide some code that you started typing or something similar? You can make a method where you trigger the push notification when the API call returns after purchase. Here is a repo that might help [link](https://github.com/afzalali15/flutter_alarm_clock), try to clone it and go through the code, and try to implement it in your project. it uses the package I mentioned above, the local notification package.

Comment: in this app after time push notification,but in my case i should call API every Time if return true call method to push notification it will affect performance if call it more than one time and if client close app he can't receive notification in this time.

Comment: @Nehalosama Then instead of the time you add your API call trigger, make a method that is maybe `async` or make a `Future.delayed` and when the API returns, it will trigger the method and send a push notification. With the repo I provided, I made an APK and it worked fine even when the app is in the background or closed, it doesn't work when the phone is turned off though.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks alot **@GrandMagus** for helping, this is the solution of my question

```
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
      FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
  Timer timer;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    var initializationSettingsAndroid =
        AndroidInitializationSettings('flutter_devs');
    var initializationSettingsIOs = IOSInitializationSettings();
    var initSetttings = InitializationSettings(
        initializationSettingsAndroid, initializationSettingsIOs);

    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initSetttings,
        onSelectNotification: onSelectNotification);
    timer=Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 15), (Timer t) => showNotification());
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    timer?.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }
  Future onSelectNotification(String payload) {
    Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) {
      return MyApp();
    }));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        title: new Text('Flutter notification demo'),
      ),
    );
  }
```